# Consuming a Kotlin Function with an Argument in a Java file using the correct syntax

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a variable called `onItemSelected` in a **Kotlin** file

```
   var onItemSelected: ((String) -> Void)? = null
```

In a **Java** file I am trying to set that variable, but am unable to figure out the correct syntax.

The lambda expression keeps wanting to return a Void, however, when I return a void, then it doesn't compile.

```
    binding.myCustomView.getOnItemSelected() = (item, Void) -> {
        //What should happen here?
        Log.i("Test", item);
        return;
    };
```

I have tried various syntax, but I can't seem to get it correct.

What is the proper way to set a variable with a function that has an argument?

Comment: Can you change the Kotlin code? It is incorrect to return `Void` *in Kotlin*.

Comment: I can change the Kotlin code @Sweeper. I originally had Unit as the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, a function that doesn't return a value should return `Unit`, not `java.lang.Void`. In fact, this is true in Java too - in Java you should return `void`, not `java.lang.Void`.

So change the Kotlin code to:

```
var onItemSelected: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
```

Now in the Java code, you need to return `kotlin.Unit.INSTANCE`, because that is the only instance of `Unit` there exists (`Unit` is declared as an `object`). Returning `Unit.INSTANCE` is implicit if you are doing this in Kotlin, but you need to do this explicitly in Java.

```
import kotlin.Unit;

// ...

binding.setOnItemSelected(item -> {
    System.out.println(item);
    // do your thing with item...
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```